# Vite React app adding CDN url to Axios post url

Tags: reactjs, axios, azure-web-app-service, vite

I have a Vite React static web app deployed to Azure with a `VITE_API_URL` env variable which points to my backend `*.azurewebsites.net` and in my code I add `/login/` for example.

```js
const response = await axios.post(
   `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/login/`, {
       username,
       password,
   }, {
       headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       },
   }
);
```

What I have seen though is that in my Azure static web app deployed instance when making the same call, it does: CDN name + VITE_API_URL + / login/

Actual url:
https://app.--.online/--.azurewebsites.net/login/

In my local env it just does the usual pointing to localhost800 without the base url prefix.

Does anyone know why my static web app is adding the CDN name as a prefix to all my Axios calls?

Comment: Can you share the backend code in the question?

Comment: The code provided is a react component for logging in. My backend is written in django and runs on the url *.azurewebsites.net. The only thing is that my react/vite frontend does a call to https://app.--.online/--.azurewebsites.net/login/ instead of --.azurewebsites.net/login/. While my env variable VITE_API_URL only has the latter configured

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the `https://` prefix in your `.env` value. Can you provide an example of your `.env` file?

Comment: @Phil This was actually it lol, did not know i had to add that. My bad <3. Thanks for your help